# True/false statements in MSSQL without < > and =

Tags: sql-injection

How can i make a true/false statements in MSSQL without the following symbols:

```
<,>,=
```

?
Everything i can think of, e.g:

```
or 1=1-- (true)
or 1>1 (false)
and 2<>3 (true)
```

Makes use of those characters, is it even possible to do this? Via operators like & possibly?
Thanks.

Comment: `NULL IS NULL` and `1 IS NOT NULL`, `1 IN (1, 2, 3)`, `'meow' LIKE 'meow'`, `'meow' NOT LIKE 'woof'`, `42 BETWEEN 40 AND 50` maybe? Can't test atm.

Answer (score 1):

There are many internal functions which can evaluate to true or false that don't use <, >, or =.  Examples could be string compare (strcmp).

In some databases you can just say 'TRUE'.  In MySQL you could try '1 IS TRUE', which should be true.

http://www.owasp.org/images/5/56/OWASP_Testing_Guide_v3.pdf

Maybe read the OWASP sql-injection guide?